# Trouble reusing UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I run the code below, it sometimes make changes for other cells than the one its actually ment for. It sets votes that is from another post.
Any idea why ?

*show/hide* votesView is just **votesView.isHidden = true/false** for the views
*enable/disable* Btns is just **btns.isEnabled = true/false** for the Buttons.
Both if these works fine.

This is my code for PostCell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    hideVoteViews()


    let ref = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT
    let likeRef = ref.child("likes")

    likeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(self.post.postKey){
            self.setVotesLbl()
            self.showVoteViews()
            self.disableBtns()
        } else {
            self.hideVoteViews()
            self.enableBtns()
        }
    }

}
```

setVotesLbl function:

```
 func setVotesLbl(){
    if let votes = self.post?.altAVotes{
        self.altAVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
    }
    if let votes = self.post?.altBVotes{
        self.altBVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
    }
    if let votes = self.post?.altCVotes{
        self.altCVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
    }
    if let votes = self.post?.altDVotes{
        self.altDVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do not run code in the **view** which is supposed to belong to the **controller** or the **model**.

Comment: Update the labels in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your view controller instead

Comment: Could you please take a look at the answer I accepted. It works perfectly, but all of you suggesting to run the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath makes me unsure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of re-usability of the UITableview "awakeFromNib()" of the PostCell would not called every time for the "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell". To achieve this you have to Call:

```
func getCellData()
{
    hideVoteViews()
    let ref = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT
    let likeRef = ref.child("likes")

    likeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(self.post.postKey){
            self.setVotesLbl()
            self.showVoteViews()
            self.disableBtns()
        } else {
            self.hideVoteViews()
            self.enableBtns()
        }
    }
}
```

in :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
super.prepareForReuse()
hideVoteViews()
getCellData()
```

}

and also in:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    hideVoteViews()
    getCellData()
}
```

I hope this will resolve the issue :)

Comment: This worked perfectly! I see some answer suggest that I should set the labels in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Do you know why ?

Comment: Those answers are for the re-usability problem but in your case firebase data and re-usability both are effecting the tableview cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set an observer while awaking a cell from nib. Because while reusing the cell awakefromnib of PostCell will not get called and hence the data of old cell will be reflected to your reused cell.
The better way is to set a observer to your "likes" root node and store the value in you data structure. After that you can reload the table using this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the text of **all labels**, or the previous text will be reused.

You should also use `NumberFormatter` for converting numeric values to numbers instead of creating string literals from them.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()

if let aVotes = post?.altAVotes {
    altAVotesLbl.text = formatter.string(from: aVotes as NSNumber)
} else {
    altAVotesLbl.text = ""
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to customize your cells in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** not in awakeFromNib.

Second, You need to reset your label and views before the cell is reused by **overriding prepareForReuse**.

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    hideVoteViews()
    self.altAVotesLbl.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the answer I accepted? Why should I customize the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath compared to the code in the answer when that works? just really unsure here..